# Fatal error: Call to a member function setName() on a non-object

Tags: php, magento

I created one module in magento Local->Vehicle->Bike

In controller i write code for model:

$model_obj = Mage::getModel('bike/honda');
 $model_obj->setName( $name );

It gives error like

Fatal error: Call to a member function setName() on a non-object in /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento/app/code/local/Vehicle/Bike/controllers/IndexController.php on line 40

Answer (score 0):

Your call

```
Mage::getModel('bike/honda')
```

returns null. That's why $model_obj is a non-object and you get that error.

Answer (score 0):

There is no function named setName() in the model bike/honda or try to use $this->model_obj->setName( $name );

Comment: This is an incorrect guess. This error is indicating that `$model_obj` is not an object. If there were no method `setName()`, the error would be: `Fatal error: Call to undefined method`.